# How to use GUITexture in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie to unity. I've seen GUITexture in scripting and don't know how to use it. I want to know what can I do with GUITexture and how to show that GUITexture on screen. Please help me.

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUITexture.html http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUITexture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI(Graphic User Interface) Textures, are images that can be displayed on screen and are like adding a layer over the camera. What I am mean by this is if you place a GUI Texture on the screen, no matter where the player goes, it where always appear in the same position relative to the players camera. A good example of using GUI Textures would be if you wanted to make a health bar that is always displayed in the corner of a players view.
How to use GUI Textures:

```
public class TestGUI {
     //declare a texture, you can do this multiple ways
     public Texture textureType1;
     //this type is usually more blurry because it is being rendered as a texture rather than a plain image
     public 2DTexture textureTyple2;
     //this type is less blurry than Texture, and is used for 2D elements
     public GUITexture textureType3;
     //this type is the clearest and is meant solely for GUI

     public void OnGUI()
     {
          GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(xOffset, yOffset, width, height), textureType3);
          //This texture is drawn but will not necessarily fill the rectangle you declared
          GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(xOffset, yOffset, width, height), textureType3, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit, true, 1.0f);
          //this texture is drawn and will be scaled to fill the dimensions of the rectangle you declared with a fill aspect ratio of 1.
          //this is good for things like health bars since it doesnt matter if the image is stretched since it will most likely only be a color
     }
}
```

Comment: Warning : GUITexture and OnGUI() are part of a Legacy API and are deprecated. Be warned, as many UI tutorials are now outdated. See the new UI system on http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html

Comment: Let me look into it, my best guess is that Unity 5 now wants you to include everything inside a canvas.